# Testing if a number N is prime by its regular polygon's angles

Tags: geometry, number-theory, prime-numbers, polygons

Is it possible to tell if a number N is prime by looking at the angles of a regular N-sided polygon? For example, a regular triangle has 60 degree angles, is there a way to tell that the number 3 is prime from its polygon's sides being 60 degrees?

(Not a math person so forgive my poor explanation)

Comment: There is no simple algorithm to test whether a given number is a prime. Looking at $\frac{180(n-2)}{n}$ won't cut it.

Answer (score -4):

Suppose you test larger prime/noprime number p(n). If you know two nearest real primes p(n-1) and p(n-2) and if you consider that p(n), p(n-1), p(n-2) are sides of a triangle, then p(n) is prime when the angle between p(n-1) and p(n-2) is nearby 60 degrees.